# start service on boot

Tags: android

I am using toggleButton in my code for start/stop service. I start service using togglebutton. but when I reboot my phone I want the toggleButton to be on i.e service is started as soon as phone is on. This is my code.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"in OnCreate", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // setAppInfo();
    dba = new DBAdapter(this);
    //toggleLogging(AppSettings.getServiceRunning(MainActivity.this),
    //AppSettings.getLoggingInterval(MainActivity.this));
    addButtonListeners();
    enableControls();
    try {
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        String installDate = preferences.getString("FirstRun", null);
        if (installDate == null) {
            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            imeino = tm.getDeviceId();
            String model = getDeviceName();
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String dateString = sdf.format(new Date(System
                    .currentTimeMillis()));
            editor.putString("FirstRun", dateString);
            editor.commit();
        } else {
        }
    }// end of try
    catch (Exception e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }




}// -----------------end of create method---

private Runnable mUpdate = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
    //      TestFunction();
            //checkDatabase();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 60000);
    }
};


public void onBackPressed() 
{
    moveTaskToBack (true);
}


private void addButtonListeners() 
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"in addButtonListener", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.start_logging)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
    //((Button) findViewById(R.id.exit)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
}

private void toggleLogging(boolean isStart, int interval) 
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"in toggleLogging", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent loggerIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class), 0);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"in toggleLogging2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (isStart) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"is Start", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        manager.cancel(loggerIntent);
        AppSettings.setServiceRunning(this, false);
        AppLog.logString("Service Stopped.");
    } 
    else 
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"in stop", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setLogFileName();
        long duration = interval * 60 * 1000;
        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), duration, loggerIntent);
        AppSettings.setServiceRunning(this, true);
        AppLog.logString("Service Started with interval " + interval+ ", Logfile name: " + AppSettings.getLogFileName(this));
        AppLog.logString("Service Started with interval " + interval+ ", Logfile name: " + AppSettings.getLogFileName1(this));
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"in toggleLogging3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

private void enableControls() 
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"in enableControls", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    boolean isServiceRunning = AppSettings.getServiceRunning(this);
    String buttonText = getString(R.string.start_logging);

    if (isServiceRunning)
    {
        buttonText = getString(R.string.stop_logging);
        // ((Button)findViewById(R.id.logging_interval)).setEnabled(false);
    } 
    else 
    {
        // ((Button)findViewById(R.id.logging_interval)).setEnabled(true);
    }
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.start_logging)).setText(buttonText);
}

private void changeLoggingIntercal() 
{
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final String loggingIntervals[] = { "1 minutes", "5 minutes","30 minutes", "1 hour" };
    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.logging_interval));
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(loggingIntervals, currentIntervalChoice,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
    {
        currentIntervalChoice = which;
        setLoggingInterval(currentIntervalChoice);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
    });

    builder.show();
}

private void setLoggingInterval(int intervalChoice) 
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"in setLoggingInterval", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    int interval = 3;
    switch (intervalChoice)
    {
        case 0:
            interval = 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            interval = 5;
            break;
        case 2:
            interval = 30;
            break;
        case 3:
            interval = 60;
            break;
        default:
            interval = 1;
        break;
    }

    AppSettings.setLoggingInterval(this, interval);
}

public void setLogFileName() 
{
    String filename = "gpsdata.txt";
    String fn="gpsdata1.txt";
    AppSettings.setLogFileName(this, filename);
    AppSettings.setLogFileName1(this, fn);
}

private View.OnClickListener btnClick = new View.OnClickListener() 
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.start_logging:
            {
                toggleLogging(AppSettings.getServiceRunning(MainActivity.this),
                AppSettings.getLoggingInterval(MainActivity.this));
                enableControls();
                break;
            }

        }
    }
};
```

the application starts but service is not restarted.

Comment: Why you expect this code to be launched at phone boot?

Comment: This this thread to start the service on boot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android?rq=1

Comment: coz this app is sending data continuously to server.if phone is off. It would stop.So I want to restart the service as soon as phone is on